# SystemJS in Angular2 defaultExtension doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angular, systemjs

Something wrong with my new Angular2 application. I call my main `boot` file next way within my index.html:

```js
SystemJS.config({
    packages: {
        app: {
            format: 'register',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        }
    }
});

SystemJS.import('src/app/prod/boot').then(null, console.error.bind(console));
```

In my console i see some errors:

[image]

If i specify an extension explicity:

```js
SystemJS.import('src/app/prod/boot.js').then(null, console.error.bind(console));
```

All will be OK, but i have the same problem inside my component with import another component without specify an extension:

```js
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, RouteConfig, RouteParams} from 'angular2/router';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because your package isn't `app` but `src/app`. Either move your `index.html` inside your `src` folder or change the packages definition of your `SystemJS` config to this:

```
SystemJS.config({
    packages: {
        'src/app': {
            format: 'register',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        }
    }
});
```